# Исчезает указатель на объект(связь один ко многим) при передачи объекта в представление

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Имеется:

```
public class contextNs :DbContext{
DbSet<User> Users{get;set;}
DbSet<Message> Messages{get;set;}
}

public class User{
public int Id {get;set;}  
public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Message{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string text{get;set;}
public User User{get;set;}
}
```

При передачи в представление объект класса Message у него пропадает свойство User(User=null). При работе в контроллере это свойство присутствует.

Comment: У меня есть, код в нём ошибка: но я его вам в вопрос не впишу, а покажу другой. :) Вопрос неполон, дописывайте код.

Comment: Кода много, я скинул основное, возможно вопрос корректнее стоит задать. Вопрос: возможно ли, что при передаче объекта в представление, те ссылки которые были в его свойствах перестают быть действительными, т.к. к примеру может изменяться пространство имен и все такое. Т.е. в представлении эта ссылку указывает на несуществующий объект. Я так считаю, но не знаю верно или нет.

Comment: >>Исчезает указатель на объект<< о_О Указатели пропадают, ссылки не ссылаются, конструкторы не конструируются. Анархия в сишарпе. По существу - при передаче сущности в БД, кто там на что указывает - как самой БД, так и entity сервисам по барабану, ссылки - это объектная часть ORM, они нужны только вам. БД и сервисы entity используют только идентификаторы сущностей для связи (классический id, на пример).

Comment: Покажите для начала ту часть action, в которой вы делаете запрос к базе. У вас там что-то типа `var model = this.Db.Messages.Include(x => x.User).FirstOrDefault(); return this.View(model);` или работа с базой выделена в репозитории?